# Is a reserved vector thread-safe?

Tags: c++, stl, thread-safety

I know that in general C++ STL does not guarantee thread-safty for read & write.

What if the vector will not resize, and the read & write areas will not overlap?

Is there any problem with the code below? (Ensure that the data never exceed the reserved length of v)

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(){
        v.reserve(99999);
        startWriter();
        startReader();
    }
    void startWriter() {
        std::thread t([&](){
            while (true) {
               if (auto message = bar.recieve(); !message.is_empty()) { 
                   v.push_back(message.value());
               }
            }
        });
        t.detach();
    }
    void startReader() {
        std::thread t([&](){
            int last_idx = 0;
            while (true) {
                int new_idx = v.size();
                for (int i = last_idx; i < new_idx; ++i) {
                    v2.push_back(v[i]);
                }
                last_idx = new_idx;
                sleep(3);
            }
        });
        t.detach();
    }
private:
    vector<int> v;
    vector<int> v2;
    Bar bar;
}
```

Or I need to `v = vector<int>(99999);` and use `v[actual_size++] = message.value();` instead?

Or both of the methods are not thread-safe?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Short answer: at least officially, it's still a data race. If any thread does any writing, and any other thread reads or writes without synchronizing, it's a data race.

Comment: Your writer-thread while be incrementing `v.size` and your reader-thread will be reading `v.size` (at least once), and `v.size` is neither atomic nor mutex-synchronized, so that's undefined behavior invoked there.  (In practice, the symptom would most likely be that your reader-thread doesn't always see the expected value in `new_idx`)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner What if the reader doesn't care about the correct size()? In this example, even a shorter length reader will eventually copy the entire data

Comment: @WayneTseng: "*What if the reader doesn't care about the correct size()?*" Unless you wrote the class, you *do not know* what's going on in its internals. You don't know if it cares about `size` or not. So it's still a data race.

Comment: UB is UB, even if you don't care about it.  Once your path of execution has UB, the entire path is suspect and can do whatever.

Comment: Remember in modern machines its not as simple as processor and memory. There can be multiple levels of cacheing that can be local to the specific CPU. Because caching is not done at the single address (usually blocks) even if you are updating different locations in the vector they may be on the same cache line. So each CPU may update a local cache that would result in one update winning when synced to main memory.

Comment: @WayneTseng the programmer might not care, but the compiler's optimizer might still care -- in particular, the compiler assumes no undefined behavior exists when it does its optimizations, which means that if undefined behavior actually does exist, life can get extremely weird and non-intuitive -- and not just "in theory" but in real life... you may spend a lot of time chasing ghosts :)   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7entxbQOCc

Comment: Best to add an atomic size_t v_size to Foo and not use `v.size()`

Comment: @WayneTseng I rolled back your edit because you already have valid answer to your original question. If you have a new question please post it as a separate one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to threading, you don't really trick your way around it. If the code is not clearly, obviously thread-safe, then treat it as unsafe.

When it comes to the standard library, its very clear. `push_back` is a modifying function. There must be appropriate synchronization between that call and any other calls that act on that object from other threads; otherwise, a data race occurs.

No amount of `reserve` will change that.

Comment: @WayneTseng: You can't ask a new question in the middle of your existing one.